# Get Directory Bash Script is Called From if it's a Sym Link

Tags: bash, directory, symlink

Let's say I have a bash script called `program` stored in `/home/user/program.` But then I create a sym link to the bash script using `ln -s /home/user/program /usr/bin/program`. Then I `cd  /usr/home/anotherdirectory` and then run `program`. How do I get the bash script to print `/usr/home/anotherdirectory` to tell me where it was called from?

I tried `echo $PWD` and it only printed out /usr/bin

Comment: `type -a program`

Comment: that just prints out program is /usr/bin/program
download is /bin/program. It doesn't tell me where it was called from.

Comment: How about `pwd -P`

Comment: pwd -P still just prints out /usr/bin

Comment: It works on this side though. so something is wrong about your script maybe?

Comment: Maybe `readlink -e $PWD`?

Comment: I found the problem. The script I downloaded had "cd `$(dirname "$0")` at the top of the program. Once I deleted that line both pwd -P and readlink -e $PWD worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job in your script:

```
dirname $(readlink -e "$0")
```

From `man readlink`:

> `-e`:canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively, all components must exist